# Boost mpl for each and free functions

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl

Why this  code does not compile:

```
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

template <class T>   // specific visitor for type printing
static void print_type(T t)
    {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }


typedef mpl::vector<int, long, char*> s;
int main ()
{
    mpl::for_each<s>(print_type());
}
```

I wonder - how to make boost mpl for_each work with free functions from same class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated you need a functor.

The code below includes an additional wrap template that allows the print functor to cope with references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/mpl/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/for_each.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

template <typename T>
struct wrap {};

struct print_type
{
    template< typename T>
    void operator()( wrap<T> ) const
    {
        cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
    }
};

typedef mpl::vector<int, long&, char*> s;

int main ()
{
    mpl::for_each<s, wrap<mpl::placeholders::_1> >(print_type());
    return 0;
}
```

*Note: this code based on examples in the book 'C++ Template Metaprogramming by David Abrahams and Aleksy Gurtovoy*

Answer (score 3):

```
    mpl::for_each<s>(print_type());
```

This is wrong in a couple of ways.

First, `print_type` is a function that returns `void`. `print_type()` is an attempt to call that function. Since it returns nothing, you can't stick its non-existent return value into something else.

Second, `print_type` is a *template* function. You cannot call a template function without specifying the template parameters. So `print_type()` is ill-formed.

Third, even `mpl::for_each<s>(print_type)` doesn't work, because `print_type` is not a value (nor is it convertible to a value); it is a template. You cannot pass a template as the argument of a function. That's why visitors (for many things, not just MPL) are objects, which can have template `operator()` members.

Comment: is there any way at least to pass to visitor any refrenced value?